# How to do MouseEvents in UWP?

Tags: c#, events, uwp, mouseevent

I'm working in UWP, I've always worked in WPF and I do not know how to do a MousePassed or MouseOver event in UWP

Which one is closest to that type of WPF event wn UWP?

Comment: Hi, what happens when you try? Your question will be better received by the StackOverflow community if you edit it to show what you have tried so far and what the results were. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want PointerMoved / PointerEntered / PointerPressed events, etc. They cover all input types like Touch, Mouse and Stylus - the device type of which you can get from the event args.

You can also see this for a primer on handling pointer input in UWP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/handle-pointer-input